# How to write data to table catalina_session?

Tags: ofbiz

I am using Apache Ofbiz 17.12.04 , today I viewed all source code for discovering something new. I saw an entity, and according to a table named `catalina_session` . When I run query

```sql
SELECT * FROM catalina_session;
```

I see nothing, although I log in/log out, start/stop the application server, and have many actions in the system.

How to write data to table `catalina_session`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already answered at https://markmail.org/message/2ff45sswgbaq7rog:

> See createCatalinaSession,  updateCatalinaSession and deleteCatalinaSession
> services
>
> None of them is used OOTB